# To show module homomorphism being injective

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Suppose $R$ is a field, $M$ is a right $R$ module, and $f : R_R \rightarrow M$ is a non-zero homomorphism. Show that $f$ is injective.

My work: The homomorphism is uniquely determined by $f(1)$. If $f(1)=0$ then it is the zero homomorphism. So suppose $f(1)=m\ne0$. Then $f(r)=mr$. To show that it is injective, we need to show that $mr\ne0$ for all $r\ne0$.

So the question becomes showing that $mr\ne0$ for all $m\ne0$ and $r\ne0$.

Are my arguments correct? Then how to show $mr\ne0$ for all $m\ne0$ and $r\ne0$?

Comment: Hint: The kernel is an ideal of $R$.

Comment: and the ideals of a field are...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* Consider $\ker f$: it's an $R$-submodule of $R_R$. But the $R$-submodules of $R$ are its ideals.

*Solution:*

> $\ker f$ is an ideal of $R$. Since $R$ is a field, $\ker f$ is either $0$ or $R$. Since $f$ is a non-zero homomorphism, $\ker f$ cannot be $R$ and so must be $0$. This means that $f$ is injective.

Alternatively, we can use your argument:

> If $mr=0$ with $r\ne0$, then $m=m1=m(r(1/r))=(mr)(1/r)=0$, which means that $f$ is the zero homomorphism.

Comment: So the proof is like this? For general $R$-module homomorphisms, the kernal are sub-modules. For $R_R$, the sub-modules are ideals. If $R$ is a field, then the only two ideals are $0$ and $R$. So either it's the zero homomorphism or injective.

Comment: What if I want to prove it following my argument? Can I show that $mr\ne0$ for all $m\ne0$ and $r\ne0$?

Comment: @Kyson, see my edited answer.